# VBA : how to get the rows data while comparing to workbooks and copy the data in third workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i am trying to copy the differences  while comparing the two workbooks and past the differences in third workbook. the below code is working upto copying the first differences(row). the code not working for copying all differences (rows) of the two workbooks. please suggest how to copy the all differences

```
Sub findingdiff()
Dim FileSys, objFile, myFolder, c As Object
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb3 As ThisWorkbook
Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
FolderName = ("C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\Test\do\")
                Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(FolderName)
'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
        dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
        For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
            If InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".xls") > 0 Then
                If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
                    dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
                    strFilename = objFile.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next objFile
'opening of latest file in the folder

                Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & Application.PathSeparator & strFilename)
                Set FileSys = Nothing
                Set myFolder = Nothing
With wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh1LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh1Range = .Range("C1:C" & Sh1LastRow)
End With
 Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\Test\do\AR_Report_Excel_Version_06042017.xls")
With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh2LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh2Range = .Range("C2:C" & Sh2LastRow)
End With

'compare latest workbook with old workbook
For Each cell In Sh1Range
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _
what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
cell.EntireRow.Copy wb3.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If
Next cell
'compare  with sheet 1

For Each cell In Sh2Range
Set c = Sh1Range.Find( _
what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
cell.EntireRow.Copy wb3.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If
Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any data in column A of wb1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are pasting the differences to the same row in wb3 each time so they are just overwriting each other (assuming you have no data in column A for wb1 and wb2)

If you change the lastrow to lookup from column C and then offset by 1 this should then paste to a new row each time

```
With wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh1LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh1Range = .Range("C1:C" & Sh1LastRow)
End With

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\Test\do\AR_Report_Excel_Version_06042017.xls")
With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh2LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh2Range = .Range("C1:C" & Sh2LastRow)
End With

'compare latest workbook with old workbook
For Each cell In Sh1Range
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _
what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
Sh3LastRow = wb3.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
cell.EntireRow.Copy wb3.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Sh3LastRow).Offset(1, 0)
End If

Next cell
'compare  with sheet 1

For Each cell In Sh2Range
Set c = Sh1Range.Find( _
what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Sh3LastRow = wb3.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
cell.EntireRow.Copy wb3.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Sh3LastRow).Offset(1, 0)
End If
```

*Also you were setting sh1Range to start from row 1 but sh2Range starts from row 2. I am unsure if this was deliberate but have amended both to start from row 1

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but i don't have enough reputation to create one, so this has to do.

---

When you are declaring

```
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
```

only `wb2` is declared as `Workbook`, `wb1` is declared as `Variant`.
To declare `wb1` and `wb2` as `Workbook`, write:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
```

---

Same goes with

```
Dim FileSys, objFile, myFolder, c As Object
```

Which should be

```
Dim FileSys As Object, objFile As Object, myFolder As Object, c As Object
```